# How to show that a group is not simple using a normalizer

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $7^3p^n$ for some $n\ge3$ and $p>7$. Suppose that $P,Q$ are distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. I showed that $$|P \cap Q| = p^{n-1} \text{ and } |N_G(P\cap Q)| \ge p^{n+1}.$$ Now, I want to show that    $G$ is not simple but I am stuck at this point. I thought that  $N_G(P \cap Q) $ may be  normal in $G$ but it is not always the case. How can I show that $G$ is not simple?

*Edit. Condition on $p$ is fixed*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem

Comment: But $|P \cap Q| = p^{n-1}$ is not true in general. For example, you could have a direct product of three copies of a nonabelian group of order $21$, and that has disjoint Sylow $3$-subgroups.

Comment: I proved it for our case

Comment: I don't know what you mean - what is our case?

Comment: @TsemoAristide That's a serious sledgehammer!

Comment: @DerekHolt, under the assumption I showed the first two statements are true.

Comment: Under what assumption? I have given you a counterexample that shows that $|P \cap Q| = p^{n-1}$ is false in general, so what are you assuming when you prove it?

Comment: @DerekHolt, my bad, the condition on $p$ must be $p>7$.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is simple then the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups divides $7^3$ and is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.

We have $7-1 = 2\times 3$, $7^2-1 = 2^4\times 3$, and $7^3-1 = 2 \times 3^2 \times 19$.

So if $p>7$, then the only possibility is $p=19$ with $343$ Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Now, letting $P$ and $Q$ be distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups as in your argument, the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N_G(P \cap Q)$ must also divide $7^3$, so it must be $343$, and hence $N_G(P \cap Q) = G$, and $G$ is not simple.

Comment: I could not understand why the order of the normalizer must have the whole factor $7^3$ instead of $7^2$ for example?

Comment: Because it must have $7^3$ Sylow $p$-subgroups. and so its order must e divisible by $7^3$.